# NullPointerException - how to fix it?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

I am getting this error in those 2 classes:

```
at pages.actions.HomePageActions.searchProduct(HomePageActions.java:30)
at testcases.StandardProductPricingTest.standardProductPricingTest(StandardProductPricingTest.java:23)
```

The code for them I am providing below:

**Page.java**

```
public class Page {

    public static WebDriver driver;
  public static void initConfigurationAndLogin() {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "//src//test//resources//executables//chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

   driver.get(Constants.websiteUrl);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='userName']")).sendKeys(Constants.username);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='passwd']")).sendKeys(Constants.password);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(" //input[@name='login']")).click();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Constants.implicitWait, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

}
```

**HomePageActions.java**

```
public class HomePageActions extends Page {
    
        public HomePageLocators homePagelocators;
    
        public HomePageActions() {
    
            this.homePagelocators = new HomePageLocators();
            AjaxElementLocatorFactory factory = new AjaxElementLocatorFactory(driver, 20);
            PageFactory.initElements(factory, homePagelocators);
        }
    
        public void goToQuickOrder() {
            homePagelocators.ordersTab.click();
            homePagelocators.quickOrder.click();
    
        }
    
        public void searchProduct(String productID) throws InterruptedException {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            homePagelocators.searchText.sendKeys(productID);
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(homePagelocators.searchBtn));
            homePagelocators.searchBtn.click();
        }
    }
```

**StandardProductPricingTest.java**

```
 public class StandardProductPricingTest{
    
        public static String productID = "7100113022";
        HomePageActions home = new HomePageActions();
        GalleryPageActions galleryPage = new GalleryPageActions();
    
        @BeforeTest
        public void setUp() {
            Page.initConfigurationAndLogin();
        }
    
        @Test
        public void standardProductPricingTest() throws InterruptedException {
    
            home.searchProduct(productID);
            galleryPage.clickOnThePicture();
    
        }
    }
```

**HomePageLocators .java**

```
public class HomePageLocators {

    @FindBy(xpath = "//a[@class='hasMMMMenu MMM--order']")
    public WebElement ordersTab;
    @FindBy(linkText = "Quick Order")
    public WebElement quickOrder;
    @FindBy(id = "global-search-btn")
    public WebElement searchBtn;
    @FindBy(id = "global-search-txt")
    public WebElement searchText;

}
```

Comment: Show your `HomePageLocators` class

Comment: I have added the HomePageLocators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with below changes in `StandardProductPricingTest`

```
public class StandardProductPricingTest extends Page {
    
        public static String productID = "7100113022";
        HomePageActions home ;
        GalleryPageActions galleryPage;
    
        @BeforeTest
        public void setUp() {
            initConfigurationAndLogin();
            home = new HomePageActions();
            galleryPage = new GalleryPageActions()
        }
    
        @Test
        public void standardProductPricingTest() throws InterruptedException {
    
            home.searchProduct(productID);
            galleryPage.clickOnThePicture();
    
        }
    }
```

**Explanation**

`driver` variable in class Page.java is not initialized in a constructor instead  it happens inside a method `initConfigurationAndLogin` because of this `driver` variable is null in the class `HomePageActions.java` that's the reason exception is thrown

So to prevent this in the `test` class i have called the `initConfigurationAndLogin()` method before intializing the class `HomePageActions` so the driver variable is intialized and exception is prevented

I hope this will fix the issue

Comment: Can you add couple of words about why this should work and what was wrong with OP's code?

Comment: Refer to the update answer

Comment: Thank you. It helped :)